# AngularJS UI-Grid Sort

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How can i sort the following data response of `ui-grid` by date

```
    this.$http.get(url)
        .success(data => {
            this.$scope.gridOptions.data = data //.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
        }).finally(() => { this.$scope.loading = false; this.$scope.loadAttempted = true; });
```

I get the reponse as an array of objects and one of the properties is of type DOB, which is the one i want to sort by.

here goes a sample of my array

```
[
{
 "Name":"John",
 "DOB" : "12/07/1987"
}
{
 "Name":"Jack",
 "DOB" : "12/07/1989"
}
{
 "Name":"Sara",
 "DOB" : "12/07/1980"
}
]
```

Thanks,

Comment: So in your grid, you'll have 2 columns? Or just Name column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Javascript sort method to get your desired result like this.

```
result = response.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.DOB).getTime() - new Date(b.DOB).getTime()
})
```

The result should be something like this.

```
[
  { 
    "Name":"Sara",
    "DOB" : "12/07/1980"
  },
  {
    "Name":"John",
    "DOB" : "12/07/1987"
  },
  {
    "Name":"Jack",
    "DOB" : "12/07/1989"
  }
]
```

You can also read more about Javascript sort method on [W3Schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)